# Creating a DefaultDict with keys which are string, stored in a list

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a list of strings, like this:

```
mylist= [['I', 'am'],['stuck', 'here', 'forever']]
```

I would like to create a list of dictionaries based on this list in this fashion:

```
   mydict = [{'I':1, 'am':2},{'stuck':5, 'here':4, 'forever':7}]
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but it isnt working.

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict=defaultdict(str)
mylist= [['I', 'am'],['stuck', 'here', 'forever']]

output = [ [mydict[mylist[i][j]]=len(mylist[i][j])  for j in range(len(mylist[i]))] for i in range(len(mylist))]
```

But when I stop trying to assign values to my defaultdict, then I am able to access the elements inside the list of lists.

So for example, this works:

```
[[(mylist[i][j], len(mylist[i][j]))  for j in range(len(mylist[i]))] for i in range(len(mylist))]
```

and produces this as an output:

```
[[('I', 1), ('am', 2)], [('stuck', 5), ('here', 4), ('forever', 7)]]
```

Comment: `[{k: len(k) for k in sublist} for sublist in mylist]` ?

Comment: oh cool! Thanks Tgsmith61591. But why isnt the default dict working?

Comment: you'll want a new defaultdict per list in `mylist`. right now you have only the one instance. not to mention, assigning values in a list comprehension should syntax error right? there's also no real reason you should be using a defaultdict here.

Comment: @sihrc I understand now. Am happy to delete the question to unclutter stackexchange. Thanks so much!